# Regexp with lookarounds in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

Trying to get this to work

```
regexp(taf_input, '(?<= \s )((?: \+|\-|VC|RE|MI|BC|DR|BL|SH|TS|FZ|PR|DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP|BR|FG|FU|DU|SA|HZ||SS|DS)+ )(?= \s|$)',match)

taf_input = 'KMEM 080545Z 0806/0912 18005KT P6SM VCSH FEW025 SCT060 BKN150 TEMPO 0808/0812 6SM -SHRA BKN025 OVC060 FM081200 18008KT P6SM VCSH FEW012 BKN030 FM081700 19011G17KT P6SM VCTS SCT025CB BKN035 FM082300 21007KT P6SM VCSH FEW015 BKN040 FM090800 23004KT 6SM BR VCSH BKN009 OVC015 ='
```

Its supposed to match `vcsh`, `-shra`, `vcsh`, `vcts`, `vcsh`, `vcsh`

Not sure why its not working

The original code is in Python on line 300-305 [here](https://github.com/dmbaturin/pytaf/blob/master/lib/pytaf/taf.py).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your regex, such as a double `|` in the non capturing group and the escaping of `+`, which is a quantifier and as such does not need escaping unless you are trying to match a literal `+`.

There is no need for the lookarounds either. You can use:

```
-?(?:VC|RE|MI|BC|DR|BL|SH|TS|FZ|PR|DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP|BR|FG|FU|DU|SA|HZ|SS|DS){2,}
```

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/OWNYuY/1).

---

**MATLAB** demo:

```
>> taf_input = 'KMEM 080545Z 0806/0912 18005KT P6SM VCSH FEW025 SCT060 BKN150 TEMPO 0808/0812 6SM -SHRA BKN025 OVC060 FM081200 18008KT P6SM VCSH FEW012 BKN030 FM081700 19011G17KT P6SM VCTS SCT025CB BKN035 FM082300 21007KT P6SM VCSH FEW015 BKN040 FM090800 23004KT 6SM BR VCSH BKN009 OVC015 ='
>> regexp(taf_input,'-?(?:VC|RE|MI|BC|DR|BL|SH|TS|FZ|PR|DZ|RA|SN|SG|IC|PL|GR|GS|UP|BR|FG|FU|DU|SA|HZ|SS|DS){2,}','match')

ans =

  1×6 cell array

    {'VCSH'}    {'-SHRA'}    {'VCSH'}    {'VCTS'}    {'VCSH'}    {'VCSH'}
```